# Clojure: Has anyone made a tool for visualizing the tree structure of your code?

Tags: clojure, lisp, visualization

I'm learning Clojure (my first LISP) and in learning about the idea of "code as data" inherent to LISPs I'm curious as to if anyone has ever built a tool that will read a program and build the abstract syntax tree in a visualizer for you - possibly pre and post macro expansion?

By this, I mean a graphical depiction of a tree in something like SVG.

Comment: I have not done this for Clojure, but I've done it in at least two other Lisp systems which have/had built-in graphers -- LispWorks and Symbolics Genera.  It turns out to be pretty but not particularly informative.  It might be more informative for Clojure which I think doesn't have conses but has lists which are adjustable arrays in drag like Python.  Drawing pictures was much more useful for things like who-calls graphs in my experience.

Comment: have you checked these tools? do you think they can serve your purpose?

 - [clojure-inspector](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.inspector-api.html)
 - [rebl](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/REBL-distro)

Answer (score 2):

Really, all you have to do is [`'` (quote)](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) a form to get an AST of it. That's the beauty of lisps. Say you have the standard `every?` function:

```clj
(defn every?
  "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
   false."
  {:tag Boolean
   :added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [pred coll]
  (cond
     (nil? (seq coll)) true
     (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll))
     :else false))
```

Just quote it out to get a nested list of symbols:

```clj
; Notice the quote at the start!
'(defn every?
   "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
   false."
   {:tag Boolean
    :added "1.0"
    :static true}
   [pred coll]
   (cond
      (nil? (seq coll)) true
      (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll))
      :else false))
=>
(defn
 every?
 "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else\nfalse."
 {:tag Boolean, :added "1.0", :static true}
 [pred coll]
 (cond (nil? (seq coll)) true (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll)) :else false))
```

You can neaten it up a bit for visualization by using the standard `clojure.pprint/pprint` function (indentation indicates nesting):

```clj
(clojure.pprint/pprint
  '(defn every?
     "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
   false."
     {:tag Boolean
      :added "1.0"
      :static true}
     [pred coll]
     (cond
        (nil? (seq coll)) true
        (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll))
        :else false)))
(defn
 every?
 "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else\n   false."
 {:tag Boolean, :added "1.0", :static true}
 [pred coll]
 (cond
  (nil? (seq coll))
  true
  (pred (first coll))
  (recur pred (next coll))
  :else
  false))
```

And you can get a post-macro expansion representation by feeding a call to `macroexpand` in there:

```clj
(clojure.pprint/pprint
  (macroexpand
    '(defn every?
       "Returns true if (pred x) is logical true for every x in coll, else
   false."
       {:tag Boolean
        :added "1.0"
        :static true}
       [pred coll]
       (cond
          (nil? (seq coll)) true
          (pred (first coll)) (recur pred (next coll))
          :else false))))
(def
 every?
 (clojure.core/fn
  ([pred coll]
   (cond
    (nil? (seq coll))
    true
    (pred (first coll))
    (recur pred (next coll))
    :else
    false))))
```

If you're looking for something more than this, it's trivial to quote out some code then recursively do a search over it. You can change it into any format that you want.

Comment: So, I read the question again, and I understand that this isn't the best answer. For some reason, I read the first part as asking how to get an AST, and the rest how to visualize it. Rereading it, I see that that's not what's being asked, and the question is actually off topic. I'm assuming that's the reason for the downvote?